# how to get specific data from the sentence

Tags: java, regex, scrape

```
public class newsidlink{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

       String msg="ABCD NEWSBULLETIN01 Issued at HHSSIST NT=2147IST 28Oct2012  Name";
       //to do code 
    }
}
```

Hi I am a beginner in java.... please help me how to get the required parameters from the above string? I am interested in `NEWSBULLETIN01` and Converstion of NewsTime NT into SQL native format?

Please suggest me?

Comment: {@Chris}I tried with sub string, split methods to get the data... i am interested to get the data by the use of regular expression or pattern matching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `substring()`.
read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
   String msg="ABCD NEWSBULLETIN01 Issued at HHSSIST NT=2147IST 28Oct2012  Name";
           //to do code 
    System.out.pritnln(msg.subString(5,19));
```

by using String.split();

```
String[] arr = msg.split("\\s");

System.out.println(arr[1]);
```

Comment: That looks like a hack to me. Not a very general solution.

Comment: @maba string.split("\\s") is a hack ??

Comment: No, the whole solution with fixed substring indexes etc.

Comment: @chaitanya10: I tried with sub string, split methods to get the data... i am interested to get the data by the use of regular expression or pattern matching....

Comment: String.split() it self uses regex, \\s is a pattern to find spaces

Comment: @chaitanya10 my question here is how to match the above said word with regular expressions than using space as a regex